# How to store list of objects in TypeOrm with psql

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, psql, typeorm

I want to store list of objects in TypeOrm..
My interface is something look like this

```
interface Comments {
  blogId:number,
  writtenBy:string,
  submittedAt:Date
}
```

and I want to store it in an array in typeOrm

```
@Column({type:'<Comments>',array: true,default:"{}"})
  comments:Comments[]
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I Solve this issue by making Comments column a string/text and use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify to retrive answers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Column({type: 'jsonb', array: true, nullable: true})
testArray2: object[];
```